# Python find number in number

Tags: sql, python-3.x

I have database table name FROM ADMEDP.EDM_REFERENCES. In this table there are 2 columns REF and DOCNUMBER. What I want is when I enter number in column DOCNUMBER I will get data from column REF accordingly. But the problem is, I only want to get data contain '901" for etc so if so many data in REF I cant find exactly the one I need.

Below my code :

```
def look_up():
    lookup_document = docnum_entry.get()
    # Connect to database
    conn = pyodbc.connect(conn_str)

    # Create a cursor instance
    cursor = conn.cursor()

    cursor.execute(
        "SELECT REF FROM ADMEDP.EDM_REFERENCES WHERE DOCNUMBER in ?", lookup_document.upper())
    record = cursor.fetchone()
    print(record)

    # Commit changes
    conn.commit()

    # Close our connection
    conn.close()

    # Open document
    if record == None:
        messagebox.showwarning(title="WARNING!!!", message="Cannot find 901- document!")

    webbrowser.open(f"http://.../{record[0]}")
```

The data from REF will be like 9xx-yyyy (xx is number and y is both number and character)

Comment: `SELECT REF FROM ADMEDP.EDM_REFERENCES WHERE DOCNUMBER in ? and REF like '901%' ` Looking for this?

Comment: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/388759/why-should-i-tag-my-rdbms